# node js and mustache

Tags: javascript, node.js, mustache

I'm trying to learn nodejs. 
I want to serve a static html file using mustache and nodejs.
I create a module for start the server with this code :

```
var http = require("http");
function startServer(){
    function onRequest(request,response){
        console.log("Request received");
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-type" : "text/html" });
        response.write("hello");
        response.end();
    }
    console.log("The server is running at http://localhost:8888");
    http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
    }

exports.startServer = startServer;
```

and then I do this on the indexjs file :

```
var server = require("./server");
var util = require("util");
var fs= require("fs");
var mu = require("mu2");

function renderIndex(){
   var streamIndex = mu.compileAndRender('index.html',{"name" : "Antonio"});
    util.pimp(streamIndex, response);
}

server.startServer(renderIndex);
```

I know that I'm doing something completely wrong, but can't get where is the error. I tried to merge 2 different tutorials i was reading about nodejs.

P.S: I know that i could use express or other frameworks, but i would like to start using nodejs from scratch to understand how it really works.

Comment: Tell us where its actually failing. Do you get any kind of page load in the browser but the templating fails? Does nothing show at all?

Comment: it doesn't load the page at all. I know that i should call the function renderIndex, but even if i call it looks like the server cannot load the page.The whole idea is just for a learning that's why i don't want to use express or others framework.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your code needs to call `renderIndex()` at some point. Second, unless mustache was seriously rewritten since I last looked at it, `mu.compileAndRender` will give you back a string, which you generally need to send using `httpResponse`s `write` or `end` methods. `util.pimp` is a typo (though admittedly one that's amusing enough to be admirable); `util.pump` is now deprecated, and if you've got a `readStream` the preferred way is to call its `pipe` method with an argument corresponding to the `writeStream` you want to send it to (e.g an `httpResponse`).

I think you're trying to learn too much at once; you might be better off first learning how to use `express` to handle routing and similar stuff (ignoring express's templating/rendering abilities for the time being) and then, once you've got the hang of it, working on rendering and templating (mustache is so common and popular that you'd think express`s developers would have already integrated it, but for some reason they haven't).

Comment: do you think that using express will help me to learn nodejs? My idea was to start using directly node, without framework, I'm afraid that will be like jquery and javascript.

Comment: It's a question of how many details you need to learn at once. Sometimes it's better to start at the raw level first and then learn something built on it; other times the opposite is true. For most people, it's probably best to alternate between them; look at something "high-level" (e.g. express or jquery), get to understand it, and then think about how what it does translates into "lower level" stuff (like node's http module or the DOM API). The key is to keep the different conceptual levels from running away from each other.